Remove markers on a map
so I try to make a website in HTML, CSS and javascript where we can add markers from a csv and remove them if we want.
Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            map: null,
            markersByLayer: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {

        removeMarkers(layerName, markersByLayer) {
            console.log("coucou");
            console.log("layerName =" + layerName);
            console.log("markersByLayer[layerName]=" + markersByLayer[layerName]);
            var self = this;
            console.log("coucou numéro 2");
            if (markersByLayer[layerName]) {
                console.log("t'es bien dans le if");
                markersByLayer[layerName].forEach(function(marker) {
                self.map.removeLayer(marker);
            });
            console.log("tes sortie");
            delete markersByLayer[layerName];
            }
        },

When I add the markers:
                   if (!isNaN(lat) && !isNaN(lon)) {
                        var marker = L.circleMarker([lat, lon], { radius: 5, color: color }).addTo(self.map);

                         // Stocker le marqueur dans la variable globale ou la structure de données
                        if (!markersByLayer[couche_name]) {
                            markersByLayer[couche_name] = [];
                        }
                        markersByLayer[couche_name].push(marker);

Then I use it:
                        var couche_a_supp = formData.get('couche_a_supp');
                        console.log("couche à supp = " + couche_a_supp);
                        if (couche_a_supp) {
                
                            // Supprimer les marqueurs associés à la couche
                            self.removeMarkers(couche_a_supp, self.markersByLayer);

I can add them for now, but I tried to add them in markersByLayer to remove them with the function removeMarkers but it doesn't work... Do you know how to fix that please?

Isn't it simpler to just copy/paste the code into the question (you might also spare some world-wide silica on the way ;)? Please read [ask], then create a [mcve].
